# Why is query being called twice?

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting, simplecursoradapter, android-cursor

Hello I am useing this code

```
    Cursor mCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(PlayerContentProviderDB.CONTENT_URI, PLAYERS_PROJECTION, null, null, Players.SCORE + " ASC" + " LIMIT 2");
    this.adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.high_score, mCursor, dataColumns, viewIDs, 0);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

_

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    // System.out.println(sortOrder);
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    checkColumns(projection);
    queryBuilder.setTables(PlayerContract.Players.PLAYERS_TABLE_NAME);
    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    
    switch (uriType) {
    case ALL_SCORES:
        break;
    case SCORE_ID:
        queryBuilder.appendWhere(PlayerContract.Players.ID + "=" + uri.getLastPathSegment());
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
    
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
    System.out.println(uri.toString() + " " + projection[0] + " " + projection[1] + " " + projection[2] + " " + projection[3] + " " + selection + " " + sortOrder);
    // Notify potential listeners
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return cursor;
}
```

To try to sort and limit the return of a database, however it is not working. By inserting diagnostic print statements I have noticed that the query method of my content provider is called immediately after the above code is called. I am thinking this may have something to do with the root of my error. So my question is why is my query method being called twice?

**Update**

I now know for a fact that my error is caused by the query being called twice. On the 1st call my order by string is correct, but on the second it is null which is making my list unsorted and unlimited.

**My ListView that links to new Activity**

```
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.puzzle_selector, options));

    ListView list = this.getListView();
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (!((TextView) view).getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("HighScore")) {
                String selectionString[] = ((TextView) view).getText().toString().split(" ");
                String puzzleNumber = selectionString[1];
                System.out.println("puzzleNumber is " + puzzleNumber);

                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.currentSave), MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("selectedNumber", puzzleNumber);
                editor.commit();

                Intent passPuzzleNumberIntent = new Intent(PuzzleSelector.this, MainActivity.class);
                passPuzzleNumberIntent.putExtra("puzzleNumber", puzzleNumber);
                startActivity(passPuzzleNumberIntent);
            } else {
                Intent lookAtScoresIntent = new Intent(PuzzleSelector.this, HighScores.class);
                startActivity(lookAtScoresIntent);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where in the activity is the method being called? If it is on a list view, then it is most likely being called twice.

Comment: 1st bit of code is being called in the onCreate of an activity. Although the activity is being started by user selection from another activity's listView.

Comment: can you paste you getView method in the list adapter?

Answer (score 2):

Since the list view is laying out twice, once with no height and once again after the height has been set (common in Android), the getView is being called twice on the list associated with the adapter. To make sure that you do not layout the individuals views in a list view more than once, check to see if the view is null, and if it is then lay it out in method getView as such:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    if (convertView == null) {
        // do custom layout of view with data from cursor
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I believe I miss understood what you meant my getView before. I don't have a getView in either of my activities. Also they both extend listActivity which does have a super.getView(). However it sounds like you are likly correct in why this is happening. So is there anyother way to fix this without overrideing the method?

Comment: I would extend SimpleCursorAdapter and override getView on that